# How to create sub menu items in left navigation menu?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I will be creating left vertical (sidebar) navigation menu by referring "Example" in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/.

Below is the link where sub menu items are present as Subitem 1, Subitem 2, Subitem 3 under item 3 and item 4.

https://www.codeply.com/go/K1gXPZwV59/bootstrap-vertical-sidebar-_-accordion-menu-with-submenus

Could you please help how to create such sub menu items(Subitem 1, Subitem 2, Subitem 3) in the "Example"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want nested accordions? If so, just nest them. Snippet below uses the "Example" you referred to in your question.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"> Accordion Item #1 </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow. </div>
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExampleTwo">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOneOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOneOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOneOne"> Accordion Item #1-1 </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapseOneOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOneOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExampleTwo">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the first NESTED item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow. </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOneTwo">
                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOneTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOneTwo"> Accordion Item #1-2 </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapseOneTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOneTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExampleTwo">
                        <div class="accordion-body">
                            <strong>This is the second NESTED item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow. </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"> Accordion Item #2 </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow. </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want a list group menu inside the accordion:

```css
.accordion-body {
  /*padding: 0 !important;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--- Bootstrap Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        Accordion Item #1
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#listCollapseOne" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bs-toggle="collapse">The current link item <i class="bi bi-caret-down-fill"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="listCollapseOne">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A nested first link item</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A nested second link item</a>
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A nested third link item</a>
            </div>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A second link item</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A third link item</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">A fourth link item</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        Accordion Item #2
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
        and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not want nested accordion. Inside accordion menu, I want non accordion sub menu

Comment: @ShaileshJaiswal I updated the answer, look at the second snippet. Please hit "Accept" if this is what you want.